# Geofencing not working after returning from abroad (roaming)

Tags: android, geofencing, android-geofence

I have an Android Geofencing App which is working quite good. I am not sure, but I think, that after returning from abroad it almost stops to get updates from the Google Services. The user can switch from Google Service to the Pathsense Service, which also does not work after coming back from abroad.

What do I have to consider in my App? Am I missing something special, if the device switches to roaming and back?

Comment: Are you still getting wifi scans, and have you been able to reconnect to the internet since traveling abroad? I have a feeling you don't have lookup tables for the region you are in, which is why network points aren't coming back, except for probably cell tower locations.

Comment: @Pablo How can I see, if I am getting wifi scans and how to check the lookup tables?
And yes, I am reconnected to the internet.

Comment: Well, the lookup tables you can't see. It's used at the OS level to estimate location based on wifi scans. The device needs to be connected to the internet so they can download if you are in a new area. As for the wifi scans, just open up your wifi settings and see what wifi spots are in your area. Also, wouldn't hurt to double check your location settings to make sure you don't have it set to GPS only.